# How how do I write a knex migration file to automatically update existing Database

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I want to create a migration file for the following query

```
`insert into table1(column1)
select o.name from original_table as o`



`update original_table as o
set new_column = (select t1.id from table1 as t1 
where t.column1 = o.old_column)`
```

So far I came up with this. The first part works but I am stuck with the second part

```
`exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
return Promise.resolve()
.then(() => knex('original_table').select('old_column'))
.then((rows) => knex('table1').insert(rows))
.then(() => knex('table1 as t').select(['t.column1', 
'column2']).join('original_table
 as o', 'o.old_column', 't.column2'))
.then((rows) => knex('original_tableas 
o').whereIn('original_table.old_column', rows.column2).update('column2', 
 rows.column1)) 
};
exports.down = function (knex) {
return Promise.resolve()
.then(() => console.log("Deletes updated records"));
};`
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First query is actually pretty inconvenient to form with knex, but `knex.raw` can do pretty much anything. Following would be the most knexy way I can think of to write it:

```
exports.up = async (knex) => {
  // insert into table1(column1) select o.name from original_table as o
  await knex.raw('insert into ?? (??) ??', ['table1', 'column1', knex('original_table').select('name')]);  

  // update original_table as o set 
  //     new_column = (
  //       select t1.id from table1 as t1 where t1.column = o.old_column
  //     )
  await knex('original_table as o').update({
    new_column: knex('table1 as t1').select('id').where('t1.column', 'o.old_column') 
  });
}
```